# Não tenho certeza se a minha classe realmente está correta

Tags: php, mysql

a algum tempo atrás eu resolvi montar essa classe para facilitar a minha vida, não irei colocar ela completa para não ficar uma postagem grande demais, essa classe para fazer um insert você manda assim `$Classe->Query("NOME_DA_TABELA",$ARRAY,"insert", "");` as informações da coluna são enviadas por array pelo `$_POST` " $_POST['nome_da_coluna'] " do form, e sem eu precisar ficar montando querys ela monta tudo e envia.

**Resumindo**...

*ela pega os dados de um form e faz insert/update com 1 linha e o minimo de informações.*

***A questão é a seguinte***...
Já estou usando ela para produção, já analisei várias vezes, não sou um expert na programação e tenho medo de ela ter alguma falha de segurança ou código desnecessário, o que eu gostaria era de uma avaliação para saber se está realmente boa ou preciso mudar alguma coisa...

caso não seja o suficiente para o entendimento segue o link dela no git [Aqui](https://github.com/siglanero/controller/blob/master/class/Connect.php)

**__construct**

```php
//==============================================================================
 public $host       = "localhost";
 public $dbname     = "dbname";
 public $user       = "root";
 public $pass       = "";
 const  ID          = "id";
//==============================================================================

 function __construct(){
    try{
        $this->conn = new PDO(
            "mysql:host=$this->host;
            dbname=$this->dbname;
            charset=utf8",
            $this->user,
            $this->pass,
            array(
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'
            ));
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
 }
```

**Data**

```php
 public function Data($select,$type){
    if($type == 'fetch'){
        $select = $this->conn->prepare($select);
        $select->execute();
        return $select->fetch();
    }else if($type == 'fetchAll'){
        $select = $this->conn->prepare($select);
        $select->execute();
        return $select->fetchAll();
    }else if($type == 'update'){
        $select = $this->conn->prepare($select);
        return $select->execute();
    }
 }
```

**MagicSelect**

```php
//Método de auxilio para o método Tables aqui que ele retorna o nome das colunas

 public function MagicSelect($table){
    $select = "DESCRIBE $table";
    return Connect::Data($select,"fetchAll");
 }
```

**Tables**

```php
//Pega as tabelas do banco de dados

public function Tables($table){
    $search = Connect::MagicSelect($table);
    $count  = count($search);
    for ($i=0; $i < $count ; $i++) {
        if($search[$i]['Field'] !== self::ID){
            $result[] = $search[$i]['Field'];
        }
    }
    return $result;
 }
```

**Query**

```php
//Aqui é onde é montada toda a estrutura para o bindParam

 public function Query($table, $array, $type, $where){
    $tableInfo = Connect::Tables($table);
    $fieldA     = "";
    $fieldB     = "";
    $field      = "";
    $count      = count($tableInfo);

 //CASO SEJA insert =========================== * * *
    if($type == "insert"){
        foreach ($tableInfo as $index => $value) {
            if($index+1 < $count){
                $fieldA .= $value . ", ";
                $fieldB .= ":".strtoupper($value).", ";
                $fieldA_array[] = $value;
                $fieldB_array[] = ":".strtoupper($value);
            }else{
                $fieldA .= $value;
                $fieldB .= ":".strtoupper($value);
                $fieldA_array[] = $value;
                $fieldB_array[] = ":".strtoupper($value);
            }
        }
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare(
"INSERT INTO $table ($fieldA) VALUES ($fieldB) $where"
);
        for ($i=0; $i < count($fieldA_array) ; $i++) {
            $stmt->bindParam($fieldB_array[$i], $array[$fieldA_array[$i]]);
        }
        $stmt->execute();
 //CASO SEJA update =========================== * * *
    }else if($type == "update"){
        foreach ($tableInfo as $index => $value) {
            if($index+1 < $count){
                $field .= $value . " = :".strtoupper($value).", ";
                $fieldA_array[] = ":".strtoupper($value);
                $fieldB_array[] = $value;
            }else{
                $field .= $value . " = :".strtoupper($value);
                $fieldA_array[] = ":".strtoupper($value);
                $fieldB_array[] = $value;
            }
        }
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE $table SET $field WHERE $where");
        for ($i=0; $i < count($fieldA_array) ; $i++) {
            $stmt->bindParam($fieldA_array[$i], $array[$fieldB_array[$i]]);
        }
        return $stmt->execute();
    }
    return;
 }
```

*ps*:. primeira pergunta aqui na comunidade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pontos a serem melhorados:

- Encapsular os atributos de conexão do banco de dados.
- Remover a conexão do banco de dados do método construtor da classe e criar um método especifico para isso e outro método para desconectar.
- Tratar o `exception` da conexão.
- Observei que os métodos que você criou estão começando com letra maiúscula e por convenção e boa prática, nome de método e de atributo começa com letra minuscula, apenas nome da classe que tem letra maiúscula.

Comment: Obrigado pelas informações :) vou revisar aqui